# Why do I get an unused variable error for one variable but not the other even though in principle they should be the same?

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to build a linked list and for some reason I get an unused variable error when I create a newNode. What puzzles me is that when I create the head I don't get such an error. Can somebody explain what I'm doing wrong here.

And another thing, for some reason after the first iteration of the loop, it starts to print `Input:`  twice.

```
int main()
{
    char input[1];
    struct node *head = NULL;
    struct node *newNode = NULL;

    do {
        printf("\nInput: ");
        scanf(" %c", input);

        if(strcmp(input, "=") != 0) {
            if(head == NULL) {
                
                //no error
                head = addLast(head, inputToNode(input));
            }
            else {
                //error
                newNode = addLast(head, inputToNode(input));
            }
        }

    } while(strcmp(input, "=") != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is "error: variable 'newNode' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]"

Comment: `newNode` serves no purpose since you never access its value, you only set it.  `head`, on the other hand, is used, so the warning doesn't apply.  The point is that the compiler knows for certain that `newNode` can be eliminated with no change in behavior.  The same cannot be said for `head`.

Comment: What do you mean with "in principle they are same"? The message is about not using a value. As you use one of them, how are they same in that way?

Comment: Using strcmp() here to test a single character is very wrong. Just declare input as a char, rather than an array, and compare it like: if (input != '=').

Answer (score 0):

You are just assigning some data to `NewNode`, can you see somewhere in your code where `NewNode` is used ? I don't.

You should always work on the same variable, either `head` or `NewNode`.
For example, if your `head == NULL` your code behaves well, perfect.
Now, if head already exists, you just want to append your new node to head:

```
head = addLast(head, inputToNode(input))
```

If you do:

```
NewNode = addLast(head, inputToNode(input))
```

`NewNode` will always be of length 2, because you will never modify head, which will always only contains the first input, and `NewNode` will contain as second element the `inputToNode(input)`

Comment: PS, you can just see a linked list as a string, you are here trying to concatanate a string that will never change, with a new string, into a new variable that will never be reused, you will just erase the content of the variable, here `NewNode`

Answer (score 0):

> ... when I create the `head` I don't get such an error.

`head` is potentially read after the assignment read (`if(head == NULL)`) where as `newNode` is read after it is assigned.